# File upload node.js, multer, imagemagick not working

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, multipartform-data, multer

Hereunder is my code. I'm using express in the MVC template.

I'm using postman to test this route in the form-data mode. The directory is made `public/images/avatar/1510932719839-BHqhegjFMc3Qf/` only the file (picture) that I upload is not in it. I receive no errors, no problems, no crashes nothing.

[image: PostMan settings]

### app.js

```
let routes = require('./routes')(app, dbPool, passport, redisClient); 
app.use(express.static('public')); 
app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    fs.createReadStream("./public/index.html").pipe(res);
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    limit: '50mb',
    parameterLimit: 10000
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.listen(80);
```

### fileUploadRoute.js

```
let FileUploadController = 
    require('./../controllers/fileUploadController');
module.exports = function (app, dbPool, passport, redisClient) {
    let fileUploadController = new FileUploadController(dbPool, 
      redisClient);
    let uploadRouteImage = "/api/upload/image/";
    let uploadRouteFile = "/api/upload/file/";
    app.route(uploadRouteImage + "avatar")
       .post(fileUploadController.imageUploaderAvatar );
}
```

### fileUploadController.js

```
let cast = require('model-generator').Cast;
let jwt = require('json-web-token');
let PhotoUploadService =         
require('./../services/fileUpload/photoUploadService');
let coreFunctions = require('./../core_classes/CoreFunctions');
let photoUploadService,
    pdfUploadService;
module.exports = class FileUploadController {
constructor(dbPool, redisClient) {
    photoUploadService = new PhotoUploadService(dbPool, redisClient);
    pdfUploadService = new PdfUploadService(dbPool, redisClient);
}
imageUploaderAvatar(req, res) {
    let promises = [
        coreFunctions.randomFileNameGenerator() //return: 
1510932719839-BHqhegjFMc3Qf
    ];
    let promisesResults;
    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(result => {
            photoUploadService.storage(result[0], 'avatar', 255, 255)
                .then(storage => {
                    photoUploadService.upload(req.file, storage)
                        .then(result => {
                            res.status(200).json({status: "Success"})
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            res.status(400).json({error: "Something 
went wrong."})
                        })
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    res.status(400).json({error: "Something went 
wrong."})
                })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(400).json({error: error})
        });
}
```

### photoUploadService.js

```
let multer = require('multer');
let path = require('path');
let imager = require('multer-imager');
module.exports = class PhotoUploadService {
  constructor(dbPool, redisClient) {
    this.fileUploadRepository = new FileUploadRepository(dbPool);
    this.redisClient = redisClient;
  }
storage(fileName, type, width = 255, height = 255) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let location = `./public/images/${type}/${fileName}/`;
            resolve(
                imager({
                    bucket: 'bucket-name',
                    location: location,
                    dirname: 'avatar',
                    accessKeyId: 'string',
                    region: 'us-east-1',
                    acl: 'public-read',
                    secretAccessKey: 'string',
                    filename: fileName,
                    gm: {
                        width: width,
                        height: height,
                        format: 'jpg'
                    }
                }) ) })
}
upload(fieldname, storage) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        multer({
            storage: storage,
            limits: {fileSize: 1500000000000}
        }).single(fieldname);
        resolve(true);
    })
}
}
```

Comment: have you set header multipart data?

Comment: Yes I did, we using angular in the front

Comment: put log on every step and check what r u getting?also check ur folder permission.